# after rewriting page I don't get 404 page for missing pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I rewrite url using

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^other/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ other.php?g=$1 [NC,L]
```

And now I won't get 404 page for example: www.domain.com/whateverIsHere or for www.domain.com/other/whateverIsHere

The second row is for renaming blog and get the blog title, but if I enter some words... I still get a page (and not the 404 page)

I have rwrite the 404 page also

```
ErrorDocument 404 /projects/404.html
```

Thx